# Why no sweet tooth

Tags: rocket-league

So I play rocket league on the ps4 and I am trying to get the sweet tooth. Now I've tried many different tutorials to get the car and still haven't gotten it. Can anyone tell me how to get it because I've tried every way people show on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

You have to win a match with all of the following cars:

- Gizmo
- Octane
- Road Hog
- X-Devil

[Source](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/rocket-league/270087-rocket-league-trophy-guide-roadmap.html?s=a53d3f2e20bab652c8cc5e0d9f3484b1)

Comment: It should be noted that he is PS exclusive, you don't have to play any kind of online matches, and most importantly it is a known bug that he isn't unlocking for some people and should be fixed in an upcoming (next?) patch.